# Calling controller method using @Url.Action in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to call controller method by using @Url.Action in href,
how can we do the same?

```
<ul id="dvMenuInner" class="nav navbar-nav dropdown">
    <li ng-repeat="parent in menu">                                          
        <a href="#")}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="fa fa-tachometer header-icon" aria-hidden="true">
            </span>{{parent.menuname}}
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
                <a href="#">{{child.menuname}} </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li ng-repeat="children in child.childrencc"><a ng-repeat="child in parent.children" href="@Url.Action({{children.actionname}},{{children.url}})">{{children.menuname}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since URL.Action is Razor code and it will execute at server so you can not pass your client side data to it.

either you can do it as follows

```
<a href="@Url.Content("{{parent.menuname}}"+"/"+"{{parent.actionname}}")">
```

which will construct the URL controller and action name or you can do it via plain Html way

```
<a href="{{parent.menuname}}/{{parent.actionname}}">
```

by any of the above way you can redirect your link to the desired controller+action